# Urban Airship - Push Sample => APID is everytime null

Tags: android, push, sample, urbanairship.com

I'm new to android and want to use the push service of `UrbanAirship`.
I downladed the sample projects and tested the Push Sample Project, I just changed the `developmentAppKey` and the `developmentAppSecret` in `MyApplication.java`.
The app starts fine and runs without crashing, but to send push messages, I need to register an APID and I don't know how.

Furthermore I get the following log and I think the APID shouldn't be null:

```
04-22 10:17:50.716: I/Push Sample - UALib(2843): My Application onCreate - App APID: null
```

and I get this error:

```
04-22 11:58:49.763: E/Push Sample - UALib(916): com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is unknown to PackageManager. Note that an AVD emulator may not support GCM.
```

I found someone who had the same problems, but he didn't get a useful answer:
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/59269-android-pushsample-null-apid-missing-permission-that-is-really-there-

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also run into a similar problem. You should carefully check your google account data. I was using an old password which was in fact not up to date. After setting the new PW it worked for me perfectly.

Comment: I am new to urban airship, I downloaded pushsample[link](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples/tree/master/PushSample) example code from this link it shows exception please advice me required steps to run the sample program correctly.